# Unable to find root cause of random crash on tabbar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, crash

I have a side panel view (like side drawer) in my iPad app which contains tabbar having 2 tabs. This view is beyond the ipad visible screen and become visible once we pull it from left side. This get initialize always on app launch. It crashes randomly on iOS 7.0.3 and 7.0.4 mostly on iPad 4 models. I can't reproduce it in debug mode while debugger is attached and reproducing frequency is 1% or less on release build.

It will not an iOS issue but any guess or anybody faced and solved similar problem?

```
Crash report:

Hardware Model:      iPad3,4
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)

Crash report:
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  12

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38d7ebb4 syscall_thread_switch + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x38df349c _os_lock_handoff_lock_slow + 48
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38db90f8 szone_free_definite_size + 328
3   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x2e4ffb72 ripc_ReleaseClipState + 34
4   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x2e503438 ripc_EndLayer + 80
5   CoreGraphics                    0x2e1c25e8 CGContextEndTransparencyLayer + 36
6   UIKit                           0x309e4d2a -[UIImage(TabBarItemImages) _tabBarItemImageWithTintColor:selected:metrics:style:forScreenScale:] + 902
7   UIKit                           0x309e5070 -[UIImage(TabBarItemImages) _unselectedTabBarItemImageWithTintColor:metrics:style:forScreenScale:] + 36
8   UIKit                           0x309e4748 -[UITabBarItem(Static) _updateImageWithTintColor:isSelected:getImageOffset:] + 552
9   UIKit                           0x309e414c -[UITabBarItem(Static) _createViewForTabBar:showingBadge:withTint:idiom:] + 956
10  UIKit                           0x309e3d82 -[UITabBarItem(Static) _createViewForTabBar:showingBadge:idiom:] + 34
11  UIKit                           0x309e0028 -[UITabBarItem(Static) _updateViewForIdiom:positionItems:] + 156
12  UIKit                           0x309e74ca -[UITabBar(Static) _configureItems:] + 402
13  UIKit                           0x309e6b7e -[UITabBar(Static) _positionTabBarButtons:ignoringItem:] + 1270
14  UIKit                           0x309e3b38 -[UITabBar setItems:animated:] + 1352
15  UIKit                           0x309e3522 -[UITabBarController _rebuildTabBarItemsAnimated:] + 798
16  UIKit                           0x309e7a74 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 72
17  UIKit                           0x308cdcf2 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 70
18  UIKit                           0x309eb470 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 216
19  UIKit                           0x309ea8e6 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 130
20  UIKit                           0x308d66fa -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 342
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2e080800 __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 48
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2e07a21a -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 218
23  UIKit                           0x308d6876 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 722
24  UIKit                           0x30a4ccfa -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 842
25  UIKit                           0x3096aa12 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 414
26  UIKit                           0x3096a81c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
27  UIKit                           0x3096a7b4 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
28  UIKit                           0x308bc34e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 342
29  QuartzCore                      0x3054293e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 138
30  QuartzCore                      0x3053e162 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
31  QuartzCore                      0x3053dff4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
32  QuartzCore                      0x3053da08 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
33  QuartzCore                      0x3053d81a CA::Transaction::commit() + 310
34  QuartzCore                      0x30537548 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 52
35  CoreFoundation                  0x2e102f66 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
36  CoreFoundation                  0x2e1008f2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
37  CoreFoundation                  0x2e100c3e __CFRunLoopRun + 734
38  CoreFoundation                  0x2e06b46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
39  CoreFoundation                  0x2e06b24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
40  GraphicsServices                0x32d722e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
41  UIKit                           0x30920840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
42  MyApp                       0x0006b5f2 0x64000 + 30194
43  libdyld.dylib                   0x38cdaab4 start + 0


Thread 12 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38d911fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38df8a4e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38d42082 __abort + 74
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38d42034 abort + 84
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38dbf758 szone_error + 312
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38dbf9d4 free_list_checksum_botch + 24
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38dba1a4 tiny_free_list_remove_ptr + 76
7   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38db9770 szone_free_definite_size + 1984
8   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x38cf7ac2 _Block_release + 214
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x38ccae76 _dispatch_queue_drain + 370
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x38cc7f8e _dispatch_queue_invoke + 38
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x38ccb742 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x38ccb9c0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38df5dfc _pthread_wqthread + 296
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38df5cc0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Another random crash in similar case:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x311e9728 -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKey:] + 100
1   UIKit                               0x33a3e855 -[UILabel _setFont:] + 209
2   UIKit                               0x33b5a411 -[UITabBarButton initWithImage:selectedImage:label:withInsets:] + 293
3   UIKit                               0x33b59223 -[UITabBarItem(Static) _createViewForTabBar:showingBadge:withTint:idiom:] + 1171
4   UIKit                               0x33b58d87 -[UITabBarItem(Static) _createViewForTabBar:showingBadge:idiom:] + 39
5   UIKit                               0x33b5502d -[UITabBarItem(Static) _updateViewForIdiom:positionItems:] + 161
6   UIKit                               0x33b5c4cf -[UITabBar(Static) _configureItems:] + 407
7   UIKit                               0x33b5bb83 -[UITabBar(Static) _positionTabBarButtons:ignoringItem:] + 1275
8   UIKit                               0x33b58b3d -[UITabBar setItems:animated:] + 1357
9   UIKit                               0x33b58527 -[UITabBarController _rebuildTabBarItemsAnimated:] + 803
10  UIKit                               0x33b5ca79 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 77
11  UIKit                               0x33a42cf5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 73
12  UIKit                               0x33b60475 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 221
13  UIKit                               0x33b5f8eb -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 135
14  UIKit                               0x33a4b6ff -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 347
15  CoreFoundation                      0x311f5803 __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 51
16  CoreFoundation                      0x311ef21d -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 221
17  UIKit                               0x33a4b87b -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 727
18  UIKit                               0x33bc1cff -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 847
19  UIKit                               0x33adfa17 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 419
20  UIKit                               0x33adf821 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 45
21  UIKit                               0x33adf7b9 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 185
22  UIKit                               0x33a31353 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 347
23  QuartzCore                          0x336b7943 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 143
24  QuartzCore                          0x336b3167 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 351
25  QuartzCore                          0x336b2ff9 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 17
26  QuartzCore                          0x336b2a0d CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 229
27  QuartzCore                          0x336b281f CA::Transaction::commit() + 315
28  QuartzCore                          0x336ac54d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 57
29  CoreFoundation                      0x31277f69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
30  CoreFoundation                      0x312758f7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 287
31  CoreFoundation                      0x31275c43 __CFRunLoopRun + 739
32  CoreFoundation                      0x311e0471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
33  CoreFoundation                      0x311e0253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
34  GraphicsServices                    0x35ee12eb GSEventRunModal + 139
35  UIKit                               0x33a95845 UIApplicationMain + 1137
36  SofTestM                            0x000545f7 0x4d000 + 30199
```

The second crash is at time of setting font at

```
UITabBar-->UITabBarButton->UILabel (of UITabBarButton) _setFont:
```

Comment: Did you write any code in block or using GCD? if yes , show that code?

Comment: Could you share with us the code that's running on Thread 12?
From the looks of it it's trying to release a block and it fails for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this random crashes might be due to memory leaks in your application.Pardon me if i am wrong.
In your logs it is seen that you use CoreGraphics.Releasing Core Graphics( even if you have ARC) is a bit tricky as it is not 100% memory leaf proof .That is it at times takes a while to get released.
So suppose you are using core graphic objects whithin a loop then it is certain that your ipad  memory will go out of bounds.